# Jasmine looping tests

Tags: jasmine

I have written a NodeJs client that generates API requests for various combinations and stores the responses in an array. By looping a Jasmine script I am trying to assert them. However my tests run before it initialize the API responses array. I have tried two approaches and no luck so far.

## Approach 1:

```html
var answersReq = require('../requests/answers_request');

var data = answersReq.answers(function(results) {
 return results;
})

describe("Answer API test", function() {

 function runTest(context) {
  describe("test array suite", function() {
   it("test array", function(done) {
    expect(context).not.toBeNull();
    done();
   });
  });
 }

 for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  runTest(data[i]);
 }

});
```

## Approach 2:

```html
var answersReq = require('../requests/answers_request');

var data;

describe("Answer API test", function() {

 beforeAll(function(done) {
  data = answersReq.answers(function(results) {
   data = results;
   done();
  })
 });

 function runTest(context) {
  describe("test array suite", function() {
   it("test array", function(done) {
    expect(context).not.toBeNull();
    done();
   });
  });
 }

 for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  runTest(data[i]);
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

works for me, double check what's in `data`

```js
/*** CODE ***/
var data = [1,1,1,1,1]
describe("Answer API test", function() {

 function runTest(context) {
  describe("test array suite", function() {
   it("test array", function(done) {
    expect(context).not.toBeNull();
    done();
   });
  });
 }

 for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  runTest(data[i]);
 }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/boot.min.js"></script>
```